# How to get a host name for my web server

Tags: dns, self-hosting

I have set up an ubuntu server on my local network. I have set up port forwarding on my router so that my tomcat application server that I have running on my ubuntu server can be publicly accessed at:

```
http://<my router's IP>:8080/
```

Is there a free way to create a domain name so that my app server will be publicly available at something like `http://example.com`, rather than `http://<IP>:8080`?

Comment: How did you end up doing this?

Comment: Scrapped my web server and used AWS

Comment: Yeah, that's probably going to end up way faster for users and also avoid the headache of maintaining/monitoring your local stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CDN service (like CloudFlare, which has a free tier) to reverse-proxy from a domain name of your choosing to your server.  There are some limitations but if you aren't doing a lot of live updating or have interactive pages this might be a good route.

Other than that, a redirection service (that would turn your http://example.com into something like http://website.example.com:8080 after the first hit) or a custom reverse proxy (like HAProxy on a $5/month AWS t2.nano instance) might be a non-free option.